# How to limit CPU usage of Docker build command?

Tags: node.js, docker, cpu-usage, docker-build, npm-run

My Dockerfile executes `RUN npm run build` command. When I execute `docker build` command on t2.micro EC2 instance, instance freezes and does not respond (I cannot even connect with ssh). When I monitor the CPU usage, I can see that CPU usage reached to maximum level. Therefore, I have tried to limit memory usage with `--max_semi_space_size=1` and `--max_old_space_size=198` arguments but it did not work.

If I can set the CPU usage limit for the docker build command I think it might work. Can someone help me?

I'm aware that if I increase vCPU amount of the EC2 instance then I can build my application without any trouble but since it is a demo project I'm trying to deploy it on free tier.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
COPY . .
# Install dependencies
RUN node \
--max_semi_space_size=1 \
--max_old_space_size=198 \
$(which npm) ci
# Build the app
RUN node \
--max_semi_space_size=1 \
--max_old_space_size=198 \
$(which npm) run build
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the app
CMD [ "npx", "serve", "build" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

in your system, run `sudo docker info`. if you get WARNING: no swap limit support, you need to manually edit grub configuration first by running `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and adding the following line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cdgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"` and saving .

limiting cpu can then be done. for commands on limiting memory and cpu you can check this article.
[limit cpu and memory usage in container](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-memory-and-cpu-limit)

Comment: Does limiting cpu usage in containers also limit cpu usage of the docker build process? (I mean without docker in docker)